# Android webview CSS support

Tags: android, css, webview

I was recently developing a web app on android, which used [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to handle PDFs.
Now, it worked on older devices (android 8), but not on more recent emulators (android 11).
I digged a bit and the problem was the android webview version, as the library only support version 87 or higher.
On emulators with no play services, the webview version is the one shipped with the android release (61 for android 8 etc..). Using an emulator with play services, I updated the webview and it now works fine.

Here's the problem though: for the same reasons, I had to downgrade various css rules, some of those are inset, inset-inline-end, inset-inline-start etc..as well as margin/padding-inline and margin/padding-block, adding the respective -webkit alternatives where available. These rules are supported since webview 87+ though. Using them on real devices with a recent webview, those rules still don't work properly. Why is that? Are javascript and css not synced on the webview engine?

Comment: In the first paragraph you say it only worked on older devices because it requires WebView 87 or higher. That doesn't make sense to me.